# React HOC can't resolve import

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am creating my first HOC in react and I have hit a snag. I import a Contentservice inside the class HOC and I have a simple Page class that is wrapped by the WithBackend.

When i navigate to the page component using react Route i get the get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPage' of undefined
```

When i debug the code, i can see the service is available in the constructor but when it gets to the getPage method, i get the alert(id) but then it breaks on the line

```
      this.service.getPage(id);
```

This is the wrapper function:

```js
import React from "react";
import ContentService from "./ContentService";

const WithBackend = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.service = new ContentService();
    }

    getPage(id) {
      alert(id);
      this.service.getPage(id);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent getPage={this.getPage} {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return HOC;
};

export default WithBackend;
```

This is the component that is wrapped:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import WithBackend from "./WithBackend";


class PageX extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPage("123");
  }
}
const Page = WithBackend(PageX);
export default Page;
```

This is the ContentService class:

```js
class ContentService {
  getPage(id) {
    alert(id);
    return "Some page";
  }
}

export default ContentService;
```

Can anyone see what i am doing wrong please? Also I am only changing the name of my page to PageX so i can import if after it is being wrapped by the name Page. Is this necessary? I rather just keep the whole thing named page.

I would appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your code

```js
const WithBackend = (WrappedComponent) => {
  class HOC extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.service = new ContentService();
      this.getPage = this.getPage.bind(this) // <-- Add this
    }

    getPage(id) {
      alert(id);
      this.service.getPage(id);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent getPage={this.getPage} {...this.props} />;
    }
  }
  return HOC;
};
```

I would also encourage you to read about how this binding works in javascript.
Here is a [link](https://ui.dev/this-keyword-call-apply-bind-javascript/) to a blog that I liked.

Comment: Great! That was it! I have read about it but i keep forgetting it! Thank you!

Comment: Mind you, come to think about it, this is different in the sense that i use bind when i am calling a function such as onClick but it hasn't been necessary when it is a normal method call. I am pretty new to react so no surprises here.

Comment: This is not really about react. It's just that the value of this in a non-arrow function changes depended on how you're calling it. so in your case at the time of calling the function this -> PageX instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this` instance to `getPage`, the [recommended way](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#bind-in-constructor-es2015) is using arrow function:

```
getPage = (id) => {
  alert(id);
  this.service.getPage(id);
}

// Or in constructor
this.getPage = this.getPage.bind(this);

// Or in the event itself
onClick={this.getPage.bind(this)}
```